# Cartodb.js: Uncaught TypeError: layers is not a function

Tags: carto, carto-js

Here is my code:

```
    cartodb.createVis(map, 'https://blahblah/viz.json')
      .done(function(vis, layers) {
        console.log("Layers has " + layers.length + " layers.");
        layers(1).setInteraction(true)
        ...
```

when it gets to the last line, I get the error above. Is the syntax wrong or something? I am inexperienced with js and html. The previous line resolves fine, I get the message "Layers has 3 layers" in the console.

I am including cartodb.js 3.15.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is with brackets, not parens. In other words the correct syntax is:

```
layers[1].setInteraction(true)
```

not

```
layers(1).setInteraction(true)
```

Comment: That's it. If you check your viz.json, you can learn more about the layers structure. In a viz, regularly layers[0] is the basemap, and layers[1] are the data layers. Other layer types such as Torque layers would come as  another independent layer such as layers[2].